# Group by In Prisma

Tags: prisma

I Have two Prisma Model Order and Order Process Type, I want to count the Order base on order process type
i want the Result Like this

```html
[
    {
        "_count": {
            "_all": 2
        },
        "orderProcessTypeId": 1,
        "processName": "In Progress"
    },
    {
        "_count": {
            "_all": 1
        },
        "orderProcessTypeId": 2,
         "processName": "Completed"
    }
]
```

```html
const data = await prisma.order.groupBy({
      by: ['orderProcessTypeId'],
      _count: {
        _all: true,
      },
    
    });
```

But in the Result i get only orderProcessTypeId But i want the Process Type name also

1:Order

```html
model Order {
  orderId            Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  orderDate          DateTime         @default(now())
  orderProcessTypeId Int
  orderProcessType   OrderProcessType @relation(fields: [orderProcessTypeId], references: [orderProcessTypeId])
  total              Float
}
```

2:Order Process Type

```html
model OrderProcessType {
  orderProcessTypeId Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  processName       String @db.VarChar(50)
  orders              Order[]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently groupBy doesn't permit the inclusion of related model fields. There is an open issue to address this.

```html
const orderByProcessTypeId = await prisma.order.groupBy({
    by: ['orderProcessTypeId'],
    _count: {
      _all: true,
    },
  });
  
  const result = await Promise.all(orderByProcessTypeId.map(async (item) => {
    const processType = await prisma.orderProcessType.findUnique({
      where: { orderProcessTypeId: item.orderProcessTypeId },
    });
    return {
      ...item,
      processName: processType.processName,
    };
  }));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).